# The state is not updating in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I was following a tutorial on YouTube about a quiz app in react version 16. There a few variables in the state and in a function these variables are updated with the help of `setState`. The values of variables are not being updated. The following in the function which is updating these variables. This function is being called from `componentDidMount` function.

```
displayQusetions = (questions = this.state.questions, currentQuestion, nextQuestion, previousQustion) => {
   let { currentQuestionIndex } = this.state;
   if (!isEmpty(this.state.questions)) {
      questions = this.state.questions;
      currentQuestion = questions[currentQuestionIndex];
      nextQuestion = questions[currentQuestionIndex + 1];
      previousQustion = questions[currentQuestionIndex - 1];
      const answer = currentQuestion.answer;

      this.setState({
         currentQuestion,
         nextQuestion,
         previousQustion,
         answer
      })

      console.log(this.state.currentQuestion);
      console.log(this.state.nextQuestion);
      console.log(this.state.previousQustion);
      console.log(this.state.answer);
   }
}
```

I am new to react. Please help.

Comment: This question is asked nearly daily, please search. React state updates are asynchronous, so logging right after will only yield state from the current render cycle, use the `setState` callback argument to log the new state. Does this answer your question? [React setState not Updating Immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558200/react-setstate-not-updating-immediately)

Comment: use `setState`'s second argument as a callback, which will be executed **after** the state is updated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React.js, wait for setState to finish before triggering a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401635/react-js-wait-for-setstate-to-finish-before-triggering-a-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check the state update value in **callback**

```
this.setState({
                currentQuestion,
                nextQuestion,
                previousQustion,
                answer
            },()=>{
            console.log(this.state.currentQuestion);
            console.log(this.state.nextQuestion);
            console.log(this.state.previousQustion);
            console.log(this.state.answer);

})
```