# React ignore event until setState finished setting the usestate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm have to match a note to an incoming note detected by the microphone. I'm using a fft to detect the pitch and matches that to the next closest note. It triggers the handleNoteEvent about 10x/s. The problem is since `setNote` is async the if statement == true multiple times, until `setState` has finished setting the value which subsequently causes the app to rerender multiple times. How can I wait until `setState` has finished while using react hooks? (currentNote is use by multiple children)

**EDIT**: `setState` with hooks doesn't seem to return a promise or take a callback if I understand the docs correctly

**EDIT 2**: I think I have to clarify my issue: I somehow need to ignore incoming events after the if becomes true, until `setState` has finished setting currentNote to a new note object.

```js
function App() {
const [currentNote, setNote] = useState(new Note());

//Event handler that gets the event from the fft tuner multiple times a second
const handleNoteEvent = (fftNote) => {
    if (currentNote == fftNote)) {
      console.log('match');
      nextNote();
    }
//The problem here is the nextNote() is fired multiple times since setNote is async. How can I ignore all incoming events while setNote is not finished?
const nextNote = () => {setNote(new Note())};
...
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React.js, wait for setState to finish before triggering a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401635/react-js-wait-for-setstate-to-finish-before-triggering-a-function)

Comment: This is not working for a functional component. setState in functional component does not accept the second argument.

Comment: How did `setNote` become async? AFAIK, `setNote` is sync because it's React useState hook.

Comment: Well the value of current note is only changed after about 500ms, thats why I figured it was async

Comment: Is it because `Note` constructor is expensive?

Comment: Yes the note class does some calculation, but nothing which should take too long. Might explain the delay too though

Answer (score 0):

You will have to handle what happens after the `setNote` in another `useEffect`. Something like :

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  // Triggered only once when your component mounts (= componentDidMount in class component)
}, []);

React.useEffect(() => {
  // It is only triggered when not changes.
  // Do your things after setting notes here.
  // Be careful about looping. If you set note here, you'll need to check the value as you did in your exemple to prevent updating note indefinitely
}, [note]);
```

You are not limited to one useEffect or one hook in general. Split your tasks with multiple `useState` and `useEffect` if needed.

Comment: Oh thanks I'll give that a go asap. I tried that already but had the recursion problem you mentioned.
If I check the state there it has already finished setting?

Comment: Yes, this is the purpose of the dependencies in a useEffect, it is triggered AFTER the deps changes.

Comment: Well, unfortunatly that still leaves me with the same problem, since I the event is triggered multiple times anyways and I don't know how to ignore it

Comment: @Nils There might be something wrong with your check to differentiate two notes then. If there is no `setNote` triggerd (So if currentNote !== ffNote) then the useEffect with currentNote as dependency will not be triggered.

Comment: The problem with the useEffect is, I don't trigger any function after the note is set. Is just passes the currentNote to a child which then draws a new note. It should just ignore the notes the fft inputs until everything has finished rendering

Answer (score 0):

Well what I have now works as it should while implementing the useEffect on note change.
It seems to be quite a dirty solution and I would be grateful if anyone could tell me how to do it more clean:

```js
const [currentNote, setNote] = useState(new Note());
var waiting = false;
const handleNoteEvent = (receivedNote) => {
    if ((currentNote == receivedNote) && !waiting) {
      waiting = true;
      setNote(new Note());
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    waiting = false;
  }, [currentNote]);
```