# onChange input delay in React

Tags: typescript, input, event-handling, onchange, use-state

I've never really noticed this before; not sure if theres a bug in my code or if onChange always behaves this way, but I'm getting an input delay and am not sure how to resolve it. Heres an example of what I mean:

[image]

As you can see the console only prints the previous state which is a nuisance because that means to have the user log in they have to click the "Go" button twice for it to receive the correct state, even if the username and password has been correctly input.

My code is fairly straight forward:

```
const [state, setState] = useState<LoginStateType>(iLoginState)
const {username, password} = state

const handleChange = (event: ChangeEventType) => {
    const {name, value} = event.target
    setState({...state, [name]: value})
    console.log(username)
}

{...}

<input type="text" name="username" value={username} onChange={handleChange}/>
<input type="text" name="password" value={password} onChange={handleChange}/>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [State Updates May Be Asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

---

With hooks, this can be achieved by

```js
const [state, setState] = useState(/* ... */)

setState(/* ... */)

useEffect(() => {
  // state is guaranteed to be what you want
}, [state])
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand, can you show me an example?

Comment: Oh, i somehow confuse the hooks with the old class component. But this is still doable, and has been already answered, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67408346/15342940

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful. I ended up using useRef instead, I posted it below. Feel free to edit or comment on it if you feel there is a better way that I can achieve what im trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

setState is a async step, not get new value immediately!

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was perhaps a bit cumbersome but it gets the job done. Aside from the state (which is necessary for the useContext I have set up) I also set up two useRef constants:

```
const inputUserName = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null)
const inputPassword = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null)

{...}

<input type="text" name="username" ref={inputUserName} value={username} onChange={handleChange}/>
<input type={inputType as string} ref={inputPassword} name="password" value={password} onChange={handleChange}/>
```

So the full code I have is as follows:

```
  //-------------ADMIN STATE-------------
  const [state, setState] = useState<LoginStateType>(iLoginState)
  const {username, password} = state

  //-------------USE EFFECT-------------
    //UseEffect: this is called when the context is set, I think
  useEffect(() => {
    //dispatch must be called before submit, I think because its an asynchronous call
    dispatch(getAdminsRedux());
        setContext(localStorage.getItem('user'))
        if (context !== null){
          navigate("/admin", {replace: true})
        }

  }, [setContext, context, dispatch, navigate]);

  //-------------HANDLE CHANGE-------------
  const handleChange = (event: ChangeEventType) => {
    const {name, value} = event.target
    setState({...state, [name]: value})
  }

  //-------------HANDLE LOGIN-------------
  const handleLogin = async (event: MouseEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    admins.forEach(async (admin)  => {
      if(admin.username === inputUserName.current!.value){
        const comparedHash = compareHash(inputPassword.current!.value, admin.password)
        if (comparedHash){
          setContext(state.username)
          localStorage.setItem('user', state.username)
        }
      }
    });
  }
```